# Named Entity recognition in identity document

Tags: python, entity, extract, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to perform named entity recognition (NER) for the texts in documents like driving license. We have extracted the texts from the document. Our aim is to find which of the texts is a name, address, country, document number etc.

The python libraries NLTK and Spacy for NER didn't work as there is no sentence to understand the context.
Will training NLTK/Spacy work?
How good is regex pattern matching for Entity Extraction?

Below are the samples to extract entities,

1) “George Washington” - to be identified as name

2) “1600 Pen Avenue, Washington, D.C. 20500” - to be identified as address

Below is a sample license where there's no label or section,

[image: Sample driving license]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use any of that you already have structured data,
means data is already extracted,name will be in name section and licence no will be in licence no section,even if you have plan text after extraction name will be followed by name etc , maybe i am not understanding the scenario right

Option A: if you use regex you will know for sure that the data that is extracted is correct if the format is strict then regex is good option,
Option B: Same thing can be done with spaCy or nltk but there is no surety of data it may be correct or not and this will take a lot of working to get it done

Comment: There are different format of licenses and some of them dont have labels or structures. It'll have just the values printed line by line or on the sides. Updated the question with a sample license for reference

Comment: things that can be fetched by labels then for other you can use nlp 
https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy-ent add your text for person and loc and you may understand why nlp is not a preferred option, this is a well trained model

Comment: Any update on this solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom NER using spacy v3